# Drawing Stars with turtle in python

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I need to write a function that draws random stars based upon the question of how many stars the person wants. a=color,b=length and c,d are the starting coordinates. I am not really sure where I am going wrong any tips,hints or help would be appreciated.

```
import turtle
from random import*
def star(a,b,c,d):
    x=5
    y=0
    turtle.color(a)
    turtle.begin_fill()
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(c,d)
    turtle.pendown()
    while x>0:
        turtle.forward(b)
        turtle.right(144)
        turtle.forward(b)
        x-=1
    turtle.end_fill()

star('red',100,0,0)

def random_color():
    randvar=randrange(0,5)
    if randvar==0:
        return ('red')
    elif randvar==1:
        return ('blue')
    elif randvar==2:
        return ('green')
    elif randvar==3:
        return ('yellow')
    else:
        return ('black')

def length():
    randvar=randrange(5,71)

def x():
    randvar=randrange(-280,281)

def y():
    randvar=randrange(-200,201)

def night_sky():
   z=int(input('How many stars do you want?'))
   a=random_color
   b=length
   c=x
   d=y
   while z>0:
       star(a,b,c,d)
       z-=1
```

Comment: hey, usually people appreciate more focused questions. You should tell us what is coming out of your program and what it is you expect to come out.  When you share code make sure you are only sharing as much code as is needed to explain what's wrong.

Comment: A good thing to add to this question might be a picture of what it produces (or an error or exception that the code throws)

Comment: Ditto those comments above. However, it is greatly appreciated that you (1) have actually tried writing the program, rather than just asking for someone else to do it, and (2) included the code in your question. Many askers (new as well as not so new) do not do those things. +1 for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To call a function, put parentheses after the function name:

```
   a=random_color()
   b=length()
   c=x()
   d=y()
```

---

Make sure you call `night_sky()` at the end of the script. Currently, only

```
star('red',100,0,0)
```

is getting called. That's why you only see one star.

---

The functions `length`, `x` and `y` need to use `return`. Otherwise, `None` is returned by default.

```
def length():
    return randrange(5,71)

def x():
    return randrange(-280,281)

def y():
    return randrange(-200,201)
```

---

You need to move the statements defining `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` into the `while`-loop, lest the same star gets drawn `z` times. While we're at it, the `while`-loop can be more simply written as a `for`-loop:

```
   for i in range(z):
       a=random_color()
       b=length()
       c=x()
       d=y()
       star(a,b,c,d)
```

---

Your code will become more self-documenting if you use more descriptive variable names:

```
def star(color, side_length, x, y):
    print(color, side_length, x, y)
    turtle.color(color)
    turtle.begin_fill()
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(x, y)
    turtle.pendown()
    for i in range(5):
        turtle.forward(side_length)
        turtle.right(144)
        turtle.forward(side_length)
    turtle.end_fill()
```

---

So with these changes, the code becomes:

```
import turtle
import random

def star(color, side_length, x, y):
    print(color, side_length, x, y)
    turtle.color(color)
    turtle.begin_fill()
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(x, y)
    turtle.pendown()
    for i in range(5):
        turtle.forward(side_length)
        turtle.right(144)
        turtle.forward(side_length)
    turtle.end_fill()


def random_color():
    randvar = randrange(0, 5)
    if randvar == 0:
        return ('red')
    elif randvar == 1:
        return ('blue')
    elif randvar == 2:
        return ('green')
    elif randvar == 3:
        return ('yellow')
    else:
        return ('black')


def length():
    return random.randrange(5, 71)


def xcoord():
    return random.randrange(-280, 281)


def ycoord():
    return random.randrange(-200, 201)


def night_sky():
    z = int(input('How many stars do you want?'))
    for i in range(z):
        color = random_color()
        side_length = length()
        x = xcoord()
        y = ycoord()
        star(color, side_length, x, y)

night_sky()
```

Comment: These are all valid points (as I'm sure you know by your SO score).  But running the the program (by copying the source into IDEL), the code draws a star (albeit without asking).  Turtle seems willing to take a function for its inputs

Comment: @JasonSperske: The single star is getting drawn by the statement `star('red', 100, 0, 0)`. Notice those arguments are not function objects. If you try to call `night_sky()` and do not use parentheses in the definition of `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`, then you get errors. Python treats functions as first-class objects... The can be passed as arguments, but they mean something completely different than their return values which you get when you add parentheses.

Comment: @unutbu, totally missed that. My bad